# Paypal - fetch onApprove get variable in php

Tags: paypal, fetch

I would like to send a post variable "success" with fetch after the payment is approved. This variable will be capture by a php file and if aliright it will send a mail. But my code doesn't work. Do you have a solution ?

thanks a lot for your help

Julien

Paypal script :

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {

        return fetch("my-site-example.com/return.php", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                retour_1: "success"})
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
            console.log(jsonResponse);
        }).catch (error => {
            console.log(error)
})
```

and return.php :

```
<?php
$retour = $_POST["retour_1"];
if ($retour == "success"){
    require("../facture/mail_notification1.php");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client is sending the data as a string, so you may need to convert the string to a associative array on the PHP side first.

ex:

```
$retour = json_decode($_POST["retour_1"]);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php